# Android dev. My app can add contact on device emulator but not on my real device

Tags: android, contacts

I begin in Android development with an application based on the ContactsList and the BasicFragments examples. The application can add contacts when running on the various emulators but when I try it on my own phone it opens a small popup windows that proposes me to continue with two others applications — but not mine —; one is the one that was already installed when I bought the phone — Samsung Galaxy Trend — and the other has been installed by me. How can I prevent this applications from intervening in the process?
On my tablet (Nexus 7) there is no problem but I have CyanogenMod installed and no other applications installed.

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, I think you are missing a intent filter, try read this documentation on implicit intent and intent filter. See if it solves your problem:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html